# What is Keras ImageDataGenerator logic?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I was wondering about how the datagenerator works, especially the image multiplying part during training.

I used the generator with `.next()` and saw the results. But I am a little bit confused if it multiplies images during training.

In the lines of code below is the implementation of the generator, but the `steps_per_epoch` is just the number of the batches of my images `len(train_generator.classes) // batch_size`. So if my database consists of 1024 images, I will get 16 batches with 64 images in each, as well as I will have 16 steps per epoch. So if I am doing steps just for my initial images, where do the multiplied images go? Or maybe I don't really understand the `step_per_epoch` part?

```
# Import of the data
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        #rescale=1.0/255.0,
        rotation_range=10,
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        validation_split=0.3
        )

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode="categorical",
        subset="training"
        )

model.fit(train_generator,
                 steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator.classes) // batch_size,
                 epochs=epoch_n,
                 validation_steps=len(valid_generator.classes) // batch_size,
                 validation_data=valid_generator,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly how `ImageDataGenerator` works, it does not "multiply" your data. If you don't pass any argument during the instantiation, it will just fetch your images from the folder and feed them, unspoiled to the network.

When you add : `rotation_range`, `width_shift_range`... you are instructing the `data_generator` to apply random modification to the incoming images within the specified range. These are random augmentation during the training, they are not pushed after your done with your initial data.

Comment: Thanks Yoan for your answer, but please re-read the question. My question concerns the part of `steps_per_epoch`.

Comment: @AzatAleksanyan, it's because your question on `steps-per-epochs` comes from a misunderstanding of how the `ImageDataGenerator`works. If you don't specify `steps-per-epochs` it will default to `len(data) / batch_size` and iterate over all the data during each epoch, but you can limit the behavior to run on a specif number of steps only.

Comment: @AzatAleksanyan, this does not have an impact on the data augmentation process. It just control the amount of data accessible during each epoch.

Comment: thanks @Yoan ( i don't know why it doesn't tag you)..

So you want to say that during training in addition to my initial images it's impossible to "augment" and use these "augmented" images? As I brought an example in the question, because even if I import my images with a generator, I mention some augmentation params, but if it will do `steps_per_epoch = len(data) / batch_size`, so 16  and it will run on my initial 1024 images? During every step(16) it will go through of my mentioned `batch_size` images which is `64`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @AzatAleksanyan, I think what you got wrong is the notion of "order". The augmentation processe is applied randomly to the input data. Irrespective of wether it's the first time the image is pulled from the dataset or not. It won't use your data "un-augmented" and then apply augmentation. That's the difference. So when you say " it will run on my initial 1024 images" that's wrong, they will be augmented randomly. Does that make more sense ?

Comment: aa ok, so just a quick example, it can do the training with for example 400 unaugmented and 624 augmented images?

Comment: @AzatAleksanyan, yes but in a randomized fashion, so you don't know how many of which you have.

Comment: now it's finally and totally clear, thanks a lot !